# Unable to export database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm attempting to export a MySQL database using phpMyAdmin. On the interface I go to "export" and then go with the general settings. Export format: SQL, Character set: utf-8, compression: none.

The error message I get is:

```
Firefox can't find the file at https://<hostnamehere/cpsess3399788319/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/export.php.
```

I went into the .htaccess file and added the following because I thought this might be a memory limit error:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 512M
</IfModule>
```

This is a Wordpress database.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Doing mysqldump (for common line intereface) manually is way better than any graphic application. For example to do backup you could open command line interface (start/execute/cmd in windows) and type:

```
mysqldump -u user -p -h hostname databasename > backup_file.sql
```

and later to restore:

```
mysql -u user -p -h hostname databasename < backup_file.sql
```

Trust me, you won't regret it.

The mysqldump doc:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

A great tutorial:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Comment: phpMyAdmin does not use mysqldump internally. Besides, it's only available to those with shell access, which some hosting providers are reluctant to provide.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you have an incomplete phpMyAdmin installation (export.php is missing).